# Cakephp query only displays last value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but I can't figure it out. I have tried several ways but no luck.

This is my controller:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM spa_packages") or die(mysql_error()); 
$names=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) $names[]=$row[0]; 
mysql_free_result($result);
foreach ($names as $asd => $lol) {}
$this->set('anything', $lol);
```

This is where I display it:

```
if(!empty($anything)) {
    echo " '<option value=" . $anything . '">' . $anything . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `mysql_query` in CakePHP.  Please go back and read the beginners tutorial on accessing the database via models.

Comment: i'm in a hurry and it works, just help please

Comment: If you are using `mysql_` functions in this way there is absolutely no point in using an MVC framework just write plain old PHP.  Frameworks carry a performance cost that is paid for in the benefits they provide.  If you aren't using the benefits why pay the cost....!

Comment: -1 There is almost no  CakePHP code in this question, and an obvious logic error with your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM spa_packages") or die(mysql_error()); 

$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $names[] = $row["name"]
}
$this->set('anything', $names);

mysql_free_result($result);
```

And:

```
if(!empty($anything)) {
    foreach($anything as $name){
        echo " '<option value=" . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with @fullybaked, although this solution will provide what you want you may need to look into using some PDO or built in methods for CakePHP as these are deprecated.

Comment: perfect, apart from one syntax error, line 4 is missing a ; in the first snippet, exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that :( my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment and in more of an answer. You *are* doing something wrong.  There is absolutely no reason to use `mysql_` functions at all (they are deprecated) and you shouldn't be using any direct db access in an MVC framework like CakePHP

Your code should be more along the lines of

In your Controllers/SpaPackagesController.php index action:

```
$spaPacakges = $this->SpaPackage->find('all');
$this->set('spaPackages', $spaPackages):
```

In your Views/SpaPackages/index.ctp

```
<?php foreach ($spaPackages as $package): ?>
<!-- some html -->
<?php endforeach;?>
```

You really need to run through some CakePHP beginner tutorials as your question shows a big misunderstanding in how the framework works

Comment: adding $uses = array('SpaPackage'); is important in the Controller

Comment: Not neccesarily.  If the model is called `SpaPackage`, the table called `spa_pacakges`, and the controller `SpaPackagesController` then Cake will connect them all by convention.  You only really need `$uses` for non-default or other models.

Comment: For hex4 to be right, you have more errors in your code than the errors present in the snippet posted. Incidentally `find ('list')` is more appropriate than a find and a loop. Since you must have tested this to comment - why did you accept the other answer? It's not in your interest to continue to write 'Cake'PHP code as it appears in the question.

Comment: @AD7six very true, I agree `find('list')` is much better.  I failed to notice the result was being used in a `select` element.